# Detect outlier in dataset using sliding windows in python

Tags: python, statistics

I am trying to build sliding windows to detect outliers in my data(using window of 5). I would like to specify outliers as values beyond 3 standard deviations. Can anyone suggest how should I proceed?

Below is a small portion of my dataset:

```
Location            Height          Length       Width    
1                    150             95           18
2                    148             122          102
3                    162             127          16
4                    155             146          32
5                    230             112          96
6                    154             108          30
7                    160             127          22
8                    148             390          36
9                    159             142          28
10                   422             155          30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the mean and std:

```
>>> df.mean()
Height    188.8
Length    152.4
Width      41.0
dtype: float64
>>> df.std()
Height    85.442378
Length    85.454601
Width     31.230327
dtype: float64
```

Then you can use apply conditional selections (note here that I used the squared root of df.std just because that shows some results here, this is probably not what you want so just remove the `np.sqrt` part):

```
>>> df[df > df.mean() + 3*np.sqrt(df.std())]
       Height  Length  Width
Index
1         NaN     NaN    NaN
2         NaN     NaN  102.0
3         NaN     NaN    NaN
4         NaN     NaN    NaN
5       230.0     NaN   96.0
6         NaN     NaN    NaN
7         NaN     NaN    NaN
8         NaN   390.0    NaN
9         NaN     NaN    NaN
10      422.0     NaN    NaN

>>> df[df < df.mean() - 3*np.sqrt(df.std())]
       Height  Length  Width
Index
1       150.0    95.0   18.0
2       148.0   122.0    NaN
3         NaN     NaN   16.0
4       155.0     NaN    NaN
5         NaN   112.0    NaN
6       154.0   108.0    NaN
7       160.0     NaN   22.0
8       148.0     NaN    NaN
9       159.0     NaN    NaN
10        NaN     NaN    NaN
```